# msgbox dilemma with translator app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am building language translator for my tribe. I have about 90% it completed. the only problem i am having is that i want to have msgbox pop up and say "translation not found.", when someone enters a phrase or a word that can't be found in the text file which is read " cat | nish stu yah." I can have it pop up when the translation isn't found, but here is the problem when i type in a word that is found the msgbox pop up as well. I dont know if it has to do with that it is running a do while (true) loop or i am just not coding the translator button correctly. the code is:

```
Do While (True)
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
    If line Is Nothing Then    
        Exit Do
    End If
    Dim words As String() = line.Split("|")
    Dim word As String
    For Each word In words
        If word = TextBox1.Text Then
            TextBox2.Text = words(+1)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Translation is not available")
        End If
        If "" = TextBox1.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show("No entry was made.")
        End If
    Next
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file format is:

```
cat | nish stu yah
```

with the spaces around the `|` character, your issue is probably that `String.Split` will not remove the spaces, so in this case you will end up with:

```
words(0) = "cat "
words(1) = " nish stu yah"
```

So, if `TextBox1.Text` is "cat", it will not match.  You could change the comparison to something like this, to make it more forgiving:

```
If word.Trim().ToLower() = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() Then
```

However, you don't really need to loop through `words`, since you only want to compare the user input against the untranslated version.  You are also showing the message box for each line in the translation file.  I think you probably want something like this (completely untested):

```
If "" = TextBox1.Text Then
    MessageBox.Show("No entry was made.")
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim found As Boolean = False
Do While (True)
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
    If line Is Nothing Then    
        Exit Do
    End If
    Dim words As String() = line.Split("|"c)
    If words(0).Trim().ToLower() = TextBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() Then
        TextBox2.Text = words(1)
        found = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
If Not found Then
    MessageBox.Show("Translation is not available")
End If
```

Still not the most elegant code, but hopefully points you in the right direction.